# Spring tiles - How to retain the state of jsp page which is loaded previously?

Tags: spring

I am using Spring and tiles to show the pages. The issue I am facing is I have 3 links on left side of page, each link refers to one jsp file, I have three jsp files to load the same.

1. The first jsp file contains SVG diagram loaded from svg file with zooming support
2. The second jsp file contains the canvas based chart
3. Another jsp file has jqgrid

Now user click first link, the SVG diagram loaded and user zoomed to some level then user click next link the canvas based chart loaded, now the issue is when user click again the first link that first jsp file loads again and the user zoomed level reset to initial level

How to retain the JSP page which is previously loaded ?

Answer (score 1):

Store the last zoom level somewhere:

- at server-side, in the HTTP session
- at client-side, in the localStorage
- at client-side, as a parameter of the three links on the left (i.e., each time the user zooms, the three links are re-created with the new zoom level as parameter, so that when the user click on the first link, the zoom level is sent to the server)

The best solution for you depends on the architecture of your application.

Another solution would be to load everything in a single page, and have the three links display one section and hide the two others, using JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, is there any web framework which solve this issue?

Comment: Actually, I am looking for a web framework to display the pages based on server logic, but it should have an intelligence to avoid the previously loaded pages. So unnecessarily we dont need to send the static pages again and again.

Comment: That's why browser caches exist. Specify the appropriate cache headers on your static pages. I fail to see how this is related to your question, though.

Comment: Please let me know how to specify the 'cache header' on my static pages?

Comment: Ask another question, explaining what these static pages are (are they really static, or are they generated, but the generation always returns the same result?). If they're really static, tell which web server you're using.